# Use if and else in dplyr with multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with a data frame containing multiple column like this:

```
dt<-data.frame(assembly_accession=c("id1","id2","id3","id3","id4","id5","id6","id7"),
refseq_category=c("na","na","na","representative genome","na","na","na","na"),
assembly_level=c("Contigs","Contigs","Complete Genome","Complete Genome","Contigs","Contigs","Contigs","Complete Genome"),
link=c("ftp1","ftp2","ftp3","ftp4","ftp5","ftp6","ftp7","ftp8"))
```

I would like to filter all the column containing "Complete Genome" in "assembly_level" column, but if there is "representative genome" in the "refseq_category", keep it in sostitution.
As in the example, in the column "assembly_accession" I have two id3 with two different $links, they are both reported as "complete genome" in the third column, but only one is "representative genome" in the second, in that case I want to keep only the information for the represenative one.
How can I do that?
Thank you a lot

I have tried only to

```
dt %>% filter(assembly_level=="Complete Genome") %>% if(refseq_category=="representative genome") filter(.) else
```

Comment: `if` doesn't work inside a pipe.  Your `else` clause is incomplete.  Please provide the output you expect from your input, rather than simply describing it in words.

Answer (score 0):

```
dt %>%
   filter(assembly_level == 'Complete Genome',
          (refseq_category == 'representative genome')|
            all(refseq_category != 'representative genome'), 
              .by = assembly_accession)

  assembly_accession       refseq_category  assembly_level link
1                id3 representative genome Complete Genome ftp4
2                id7                    na Complete Genome ftp8
```